# Изменение надписи на кнопке?

Tags: jquery

Есть небольшой блок с кнопкой, при клике по которой показывается скрытый текст, и обратно. Вопрос вот в чем: как сделать чтобы надпись на кнопке менялась?

```css
.product-item-special {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #2669b5;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  padding: 20px 0 20px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.btn-foot {
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
p.data {
  font-family: "TahomaBold", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-align: left;
}
h3 {
  font-family: "TahomaBold", sans-serif;
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.125;
  text-align: left;
}
p {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-item-special">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p class="data">14.01.2016</p>
      <h3>Успейте купить! Акция длится до февраля!</h3>
      <p>С самого начала главной целью было предложить нашим клиентам самый широкий спектр автомобильных запасных начала главной целью было предложить нашим клиентам самый широкий спектр автомобильных запасных частей и аксессуаров, а развитие интернет–технологий
        дало возможность максимально упростить и ускорить процесс покупки.
      </p>
      <div class="hide-text" style="display: none">
        <p>Компания быстро росла, и сегодня, занимая одну из ведущих позиции на этом рынке, мы не стоим на месте. В основе проекта Cамые современные информационные технологии, собственные программные разработки, накопленная за годы работы аналитическая и
          статистическая информация по рынку, высококвалифицированный коллектив — мы делаем все для того, чтобы Вы были довольны нашей работой.
        </p>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="btn-foot" onclick="$('div.hide-text').toggle('normal');">Развернуть</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yfnc1mpn/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код ниже должен помочь с решением проблемы.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-item-special">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p class="data">14.01.2016</p>
      <h3>Успейте купить! Акция длится до февраля!</h3>
      <p>С самого начала главной целью было предложить нашим клиентам самый широкий спектр автомобильных запасных начала главной целью было предложить нашим клиентам самый широкий спектр автомобильных запасных частей и аксессуаров, а развитие интернет–технологий
        дало возможность максимально упростить и ускорить процесс покупки.
      </p>
      <div class="hide-text" style="display: none">
        <p>Компания быстро росла, и сегодня, занимая одну из ведущих позиции на этом рынке, мы не стоим на месте. В основе проекта Cамые современные информационные технологии, собственные программные разработки, накопленная за годы работы аналитическая и
          статистическая информация по рынку, высококвалифицированный коллектив — мы делаем все для того, чтобы Вы были довольны нашей работой.
        </p>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="btn-foot">Развернуть</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a.btn-foot').on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).text() == 'Развернуть') {
                $(this).text('Свернуть');
            }
            else {
                $(this).text('Развернуть');
            }
            $('div.hide-text').toggle('normal');
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

можете использовать такой вариант

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.btn-foot').on('click', function() {
        $(this).text() == 'Развернуть' ? $(this).text('Свернуть') : $(this).text('Развернуть');
        $('div.hide-text').toggle('normal');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

пример на css

```css
.product-item-special {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #2669b5;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  padding: 20px 0 60px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  
}
.btn-foot {
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
p.data {
  font-family: "TahomaBold", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-align: left;
}
h3 {
  font-family: "TahomaBold", sans-serif;
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.125;
  text-align: left;
}
p {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


.b-hide-text-container{
  position: relative;  
}

[id^=btn-more]{
  display: none;
}
[id^=btn-more] + label{
  position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
[id^=btn-more] + label:before{
  content: 'Развернуть';
  text-align: center;
  display: block;  
}
[id^=btn-more]:checked + label:before{
  content: 'Свернуть';  
}  

[id^=btn-more] + label ~ .hide-text{
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
[id^=btn-more]:checked + label ~ .hide-text{  
  max-height: 999px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-item-special">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p class="data">14.01.2016</p>
      <h3>Успейте купить! Акция длится до февраля!</h3>
      <p>С самого начала главной целью было предложить нашим клиентам самый широкий спектр автомобильных запасных начала главной целью было предложить нашим клиентам самый широкий спектр автомобильных запасных частей и аксессуаров, а развитие интернет–технологий
        дало возможность максимально упростить и ускорить процесс покупки.
      </p>
      
      <div class="b-hide-text-container">
      <input type="checkbox" class="btn-foot" id="btn-more" />
      <label for="btn-more"></label>
      
      <div class="hide-text">
        <p>Компания быстро росла, и сегодня, занимая одну из ведущих позиции на этом рынке, мы не стоим на месте. В основе проекта Cамые современные информационные технологии, собственные программные разработки, накопленная за годы работы аналитическая и
          статистическая информация по рынку, высококвалифицированный коллектив — мы делаем все для того, чтобы Вы были довольны нашей работой.
        </p>
      </div>
      </div>
      
      
     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```